# Java substring in a string

Tags: java, string, substring

I know this has question has been asked countless times.. but I can't seem to get it to work. the problems are,

1. Even converting everything to lower case doesn't work out when
   "computer" and "Comp" are entered.
2. If the string is a sentence (I add a space), it essentially skips the substring code and says "Not in the string"..

Help is appreciated.
thanks!

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("\fEnter the main string:");

String GivenString=in.next();
System.out.println("Enter the substring :");

String SubString=in.next();

GivenString.toLowerCase();
SubString.toLowerCase();

if(GivenString.indexOf(SubString)!=-1)
{
    System.out.println("Substring is in the given string.");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Substring is not in the given string.");
}
```

Comment: Please use proper naming conventions. It makes code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @syb0rg. Changing them right away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String`s are immutable and `toLowerCase()` returns a new `String` object. These lines:

```
GivenString.toLowerCase();
SubString.toLowerCase();
```

...do not modify the values in `GivenString` and `SubString`.

You would need to modify them to:

```
GivenString = GivenString.toLowerCase();
SubString = SubString.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Also, note that by convention in Java (unlike some other languages, like C#) variable names start with a lower case letter, which distinguishes them from class names.